# Libreria WPF.MDI manipulacion de mdichild C#

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos, librería

Estoy usando la libreria MDI.WPF para emular los MDI de Windows-Forms.

Inicio una instncia de un MdiChild en el momento que el usuario clickea en un boton
Le asigno un nombre, un estilo, el content, lo agrego el MdiContainer (el mdi padre) y le asigno una posición. Cuando el MainWindows sufre un cambio de tamaño el MdiChild tambien se agrande o achica en base al Window principal. Todo esto funciona perfecto, el problema es cuando quiero replicar lo mismo de cambiar el tamaño en base al Window pero con el evento StateChanged no pasa lo mismo.

> El codigo

```
 MdiChild child = new MdiChild();

    private void AbrirForm(UserControl _usrCtrl, string _Titulo, string _Name)
    {           
        child.Name = _Name;               
        child.Style = null;     
        child.Content = _usrCtrl;
        MainMdiContainer.Children.Add(child);
        child.Position = new Point(50, 25);
        this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
        this.StateChanged += MainWindow_StateChanged;

    }

    private void MainWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Esto no funciona correctamente.
        child.Width = this.Width - 300;
        child.Height = this.Height - 100;
    }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Esto funciona
       child.Width = this.Width - 300;
       child.Height = this.Height - 100;
    }

    private void MainMdiContainer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Esto funciona
       child.Width = this.Width - 300;
       child.Height = this.Height - 100;
    }
```

> Observaciones

Note que si no uso los eventos de SizeChanged de MainWindow y MainMdiContainer, maximizo y vuelvo a poner la ventana en el estado normal el MdiChild si adopta el tamaño del MainWindow (del MainWindow en estado normal).
Abajo pondre la seguidilla de acciones que acabo de explicar pero con fotos para un mejor entendimiento

> Se abre el programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Se abre el MdiChild (Preste atención a los bordes que hay del lado derecho y bajo el MdiChild) el tamaño que tiene)

[image: Cita en bloque]

> Aquí se maximiza el MainWindow, el MdiChild debería agrandarse y no lo hace.

[image: Cita en bloque]

> El MainWindow vuelve a ir a la posicion con el ancho y largo normal. (Como en la primera y segunda imagen). Aqui si hace caso al código y adopta las medidas especificadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Pruebas

Probe haciendo interrupciones para confirmar que efectivamente se este ejecutando el evento y si, el evento se ejecuta. Lo que acabo de darme cuenta es que el Width y Height del MainWindow no se modifican y siempre mantiene el tamaño de 800 x 450 aunque el MainWindow este Maximizado. En base a esto lo que hice fue `child.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized` pero me trae un error de referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Tambien probe con esto y manipular el tamaño a mano incomodamente

```
private void MainWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            child.Width = 1200;
            child.Height = 800;
        }
    }
```

Pero el resultado es parecido a lo anterior comentado anteriormente la seguidilla que debo hacer es esta

Abro el form -> Maximizo (No ocurre nada) -> Lo vuelvo al estado normal -> Se agranda y se pone en 1200x800.

Cuando Maximizo el MainWindow si hago interrupciones si entra en el if y supuestamente si cambia los valores del MdiChild. No entiendo lo que esta pasando concretamente.

Si cambio el Size del MainWindow y repito los pasos de las imagines de arriba el MdiChild funciona tal cual es decir, adopta las medidas según lo programado.

Si manipulo las propiedades Width y Height del MdiChild en cualquier otra funcion como por ejemplo en AbrirForm las propiedades se cambian correctamente.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, porqué quieres usar MDI en WPF si WPF puede manejar controles dentro de contenedores? (no Window's claro, pero si UserControls que son básicamente lo mismo) necesitas que estén siempre maximizadas esas ventanas hijas? o quieres poder minimizarlas dentro del MDI como en Forms? Por otro lado, esa interfaz que muestras es muy sencillo hacerla con un TabControl estilo vertical y haría el mismo efecto. Solo lo pregunto porque siempre me gusta contemplar alternativas.

Comment: Hola, como estas?. Acabo de leer este comentario perdon por la demora. Estoy migrando mi aplicacion en Windows Forms donde alli trabajaba muchisimo con mdi ya que resultaba muy comodo abrir la ventana de stock y a la vez tener la ventana de carga de datos. aqui queria emular lo mismo pero me dio mas dolores de cabeza que mejoras, mi idea es tener varias ventanas poder minimizarlas trbajar en paralelo con dos o tres a la vez. Que me recomiendas?

Comment: A ver, MDI tiene sus ventajas y muy buenas por cierto, pero honestamente (y es una opinión muy personal) no creo que se bueno intentar traer cosas de FORMS a WPF.. yo he tenido que desarrollar software con esa misma exigencia de tener varias cosas a la vez..y lo hice con TABS (tabcontrol)... tenia un TabControl "principal" y en cada tab un menu (admin, reportes, gestion) y los submenues eran otro tab dentro, y puedes ir cambiando de tab en tab libremente ya que las otras no se cierran ni resetean, aunque claro, hay que ser cuidadoso con el uso de memoria, pero con practica eso no es problema.

Comment: Lo que termine resolviendo fue crear una especie de tabcontrol pero sin, donde un Grid es el contenedor de los UserControl y ya. Voy a intentar mejorar un poco la estructura pero creo que va por ese lado sin mdi

Comment: Se me ocurre algo.. puedes tener un grid principal como dices, que muestre el UserControl que quieres usar (no se si usas el patrón MVVM o no) y el resto mantenerlos en una lista a un lado o abajo.. usando un stackpanel para que los apile.. y si clickeas uno de esos se cambie al grid principal y el anterior se vaya al stackpanel, y mantener eso en una List<UserControl> si usas MVVM puedes tener llenar el grid principal bindeando el SelectedItem con una propiedad de tipo UserControl... no se si se entiende.. se me acaba de ocurrir y me soluciona problemas también.. lo haré para ver si funciona.

Comment: Entiendo,a eso me refería con mejorar la estructura es exactamente lo que debería hace lo que dices, luego me cuentas :)